# Wrong 'this' reference in extending Map

Tags: javascript, dictionary, typescript, map-function

I am trying to write a simple method, on `Map<K, V>` interface. And this what I have done so far:
`MapExtensions.ts:`

```
interface Map<K, V> {
    clone(): Map<K, V>;
}

Map.prototype.clone = () => {
    var self = this;
    console.log(self);

    let retval = new Map();        
    self.forEach((value, key) => {
        retval.set(key, value);
    });

    //for (let [key, value] of self.entries()) {
    //    retval.set(key, value);
    //}
    return retval;
};
```

However, while testing the method I eventually found that the reference in `this` argument is wrongly referring to `Window` object, and thus, `self.forEach` does not work and the while testing it says `self.forEach is not a function`(same with `self.entries()`). Here is my test script:

```
test("clone test", () => {
    //Arrange
    const source = new Map().set(1, "abc").set(2, "def").set(3, "ghi");

    //Act
    const actual = source.clone.bind(source)();//This fails.
    //const actual = source.clone();//This too fails.

    //Assert
    console.log(actual);
    console.log(expected);
    deepEqual(actual, source, "Cloned correctly");
});
```

Additional Information:

1. Below is the JavaScript output generated:

   ```
   var _this = this;//It seems this is causing the problem.
   Map.prototype.clone = function () {
       var self = _this;
       var retval = new Map();
       console.log(self);
       self.forEach(function (value, key) {
           retval.set(key, value);
       });
       return retval;
   };
   ```
2. I am using Visual Studio 2015, and the default JavaScript output generator from typescript.

How to do this successfully?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you're using an arrow function. Don't use arrow functions when you need access to `this`.

```
Map.prototype.clone = function() { ... }
```

Comment: Thank You. This solved the problem :) However, I still have to wait 9 mins to accept this as answer :) In the meantime, can you please explain a little bit, what just happened here?

Comment: oh sure. arrow functions are just syntactical sugar to bind the function to the outer `this` value. i.e. the value of `this` in arrow function is the value of `this` in its parent scope. You should never use arrow functions for `prototype` methods.